# How to pass a control to Bootstrap Modal Input as soon as it pops up?

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, css

I was wondering if it is possible to pass the control to bootstrap Modal Input so that i dont have to use mouse click to focus on that.Usually i have to click on the inputas soon as modal popsup. Here is a Simple code.

```
<div class="modal fade" id="myModal1" role="dialog">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
                <h4 class="modal-title">Password authentication</h4>
            </div>
            <?php $attributes = array('class' => 'check_user_password', 'id' => 'check_user_password'); ?>
            <?php echo form_open('PswAuthentication', $attributes); ?>
                <div class="modal-body">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label>Enter password:</label>
                        <input type="password" class="form-control" name="user_password"  placeholder="Enter password">
                    </div> 
                    <div class="col-xs-1" id="courseInfo" style="display:none;">
                        <input type="hidden" name="crs_id" id="courseId" value="<?php echo set_value('crs_id'); ?>">
                        <input type="hidden" name="crs_code" id="courseCode" value="<?php echo set_value('crs_code'); ?>">                        
                    </div>
                    <input type="hidden" name="event" id="crs_event" value="<?php echo set_value('event'); ?>">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default btn-success check_user_password_btn">Submit</button>
                    </div>
                </div>
            <?php echo form_close(); ?>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**And here is the UI**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I got the Answer guys. Sorry for asking this simple Question. I just had to put Autofocus in input field.

```
<input type="password" class="form-control" name="user_password"  placeholder="Enter password" autofocus>
```

Answer (score 0):

Due to how HTML5 defines its semantics, the autofocus HTML attribute has no effect in Bootstrap modals. To achieve the same effect, use some custom JavaScript:

```
$('#myModal').on('shown.bs.modal', function () {
  $('#myInput').focus()
})
```

[Read more](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#modals)

example code here [codepen](http://codepen.io/jpI/pen/BzbYYp)